# How to install postfix>=3.5.0 on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, postfix

I've searched high and low and it seems everyone just installs the default `postfix` package (version 3.4.x)

There is a feature only available since Postfix v3.5 that I want to use.

So how do I install a newer Postfix on Focal?

Comment: Ubuntu comes in a package. every version got their packages, tested and released. Newer packages will come with newer releases, see https://packages.ubuntu.com/postfix
If you desperately want a newer version, you're always free to download and compile it by yourself. Either the newer .deb package (see link above) or direct from the project website... There are other ways (PPA, Snap), but I don't think it is a good idea to trust a 3rd party with such a security-related service as email.

Answer (score 1):

This is the downside of running LTS versions - it can be more difficult to get the latest versions of applications.

There are a couple of options, all of which are largely unsupported and at your own risk:

#### PPA with newer Postfix version

There may be a PPA with a newer [Postfix version](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/postfix) available - although I didn't find one initially.

If someone provides a PPA and keeps it updated with security fixes, then you're in luck, as you don't have to apply security fixes yourself.

#### Find a suitable Debian package

It's possible that you can install a newer [Debian package of Postfix](https://debian.pkgs.org/11/debian-main-amd64/postfix_3.5.6-1+b1_amd64.deb.html). It is highly advised that you test this first, and check dependencies manually. It may or may not work as expected (this method has worked for me for applications with very simple dependencies).

#### Compile your own version

The final option is getting the [source code](https://www.postfix.org/download.html) and compiling it yourself with the proper dependencies. This may be time-consuming.

Please note that by installing or compiling a newer package manually, you'll loose future security updates, so this can be risky methods.